# Transform list(1, 2, 3) to [1, 2, 3] in Octave

Tags: octave

As explained in question title, I'd like to use [lists](http://www.frad.t.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~miyoshi/nu2006/octave-doc-2.1.35/octave_8.html) in octave and subsequently transform lists into usual arrays. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Octave version you have?

Pelase note that on 3.2.4 I get `warning: list objects are deprecated; use cell arrays instead`.

For operations with cell arrays see [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Cell-Arrays.html#Cell-Arrays).

Comment: Also the version is indeed 3.2.4, but thanks to your advice I've solved the problem, so I no longer need lists.